# Can we use PhoneGap to build a hybrid app using IDE other than eclipse?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

If we use eclipse what version to use and what sdk we will need.Will they be different for different platforms.

Comment: Is this for iOS or Android or both?

Comment: @davidethell PhoneGap supports 7 platforms, not only android and ios.

Comment: @MiniGod, granted. I shouldn't have been quite so biased in the question, although in most of my deployments I've rarely had a customer ask for more than those two, RIM sometimes, Windows Phone never.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any IDE. It mostly depends on what device you physically have to test your app on.
If android; go eclipse,
if windows phone;  go visual studio,
if ios; go xcode.

The code is exactly the same for all platforms (although there are quirks), so it doesn't really matter what which IDE you use.

Comment: MiniGod is right. You can develop the code in whatever IDE you want, but unless you plan to use PhoneGap Build you'll still need to end up in the preferred IDE for each platform to get the app binary built.